# Storybook for React tutorial, failing to install npx -p @storybook/cli sb init

Tags: reactjs, storybook

Thanks for taking the time to look at my issue.

I am following the Storybook for React Tutorial;

## Create our application:

npx create-react-app taskbox

cd taskbox

## Add Storybook:

npx -p @storybook/cli sb init

When I run the npx -p @storybook/cli sb init command, it will fail to install and I receive this error.

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...NrtNqRHco5\nxlpsRMQzO'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-10T04_11_36_303Z-debug.log
Install for [ '@storybook/cli@latest' ] failed with code 1
```

So it looks like a cache error, I have run yarn cache clean --force. I still have the same issue.

Any help would be great!

Comment: try `npx -p @storybook/cli@5.3.19 sb init`

Answer (score 27):

Had the same issue.

Do:
`yarn add @storybook/cli --dev`
in your project.

then:
`yarn sb init`
to initialize storybook in your project.

Comment: This should be marked as an answer. I was running into issues running 'npx sb init' on WSL2 (Ubuntu) and was told Permission denied by shell. This workaround made it work, thank you! Heck, it should even be listed in the official docs as an alternate way of installing.